# How to restore Windows7 after restore ubuntu bootloader?

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

At first I will describe my situation in a few points:

1. I have installed Windows7, and then Ubuntu 11.04 on my machine. Then everything works fine and at start of system I have screen from linux where I can choose the system.
2. Then I reinstall Windows7 and install Windows 8 on other partition. Then I can choose between Win7 and win8 when I start system.
3. Then I need my Ubuntu back so I want restore my bootloader from Ubuntu. I boot Ubuntu from USB and in terminal write this commands:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

Then I get:

```
/dev/sda1               1          13      104391   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2              14        2805    22425601    5  Rozszerzona
/dev/sda3   *        2805       41968   314572800    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           41968       60802   151282688    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda5              14        2445    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2445        2805     2893824   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Next commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

I get `Installation finished. No error reported.`. And when I start my machine I have old Ubuntu start screen to choose system. Ubuntu works well. But There are no Windows 8 option.

But my primary **problem** is when I choose Windows 7 I have:

```
error: no such device ...
error: no such disk
```

so I have no idea what can I do. I really need both systems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please boot to Ubuntu and open a terminal. Then execute this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should solve the problem.

See this question: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

After booting into Ubuntu try these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and follow boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) file and put it in an usb with [UNetBootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) or in a cd by right-clicking on the ISO file and clicking on "write to disc".

Then boot the cd/usb on your computer. It should automatically open, in an lxde GUI, a windows called Boot Repair.

Follow the instructions on the window and when you restart your computer, it should be fine. Hope will help.